# В зависимости от того число или строка выполнить действие

Tags: java

Как в зависимости от того пришло число или строка, выполнить определенные действия? Сейчас делаю вот так

```
OfficeAddresses officeAddresses = null;
boolean addressIdOrMnem;
String mnem = null;
Integer id = null;

try {
    id = Integer.parseInt(request.params("address_id"));
    addressIdOrMnem = true;
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    mnem = request.params("address_id");
    addressIdOrMnem = false;
}

if (addressIdOrMnem) {
    officeAddresses = App.officeDao.getOfficeAddressById(id);
} else {
    Integer idByMnem = App.officeDao.checkOfficeAddressExistsByMnem(mnem);
    officeAddresses = App.officeDao.getOfficeAddressById(idByMnem);
}

return officeAddresses;
```

Но это как то не красиво выглядит. Оно работает, и правильно работает, но что то не нравится мне это.

Сделал вот так

```
return Optional.of(request.params("address_id"))
        .map(id -> {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(id);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                return null;
            }
        })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(id -> App.officeDao.getOfficeAddressById(id))
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            Integer addressIdInt = App.officeDao.checkOfficeAddressExistsByMnem(request.params("address_id"));
            if (addressIdInt != null) {
                return App.officeDao.getOfficeAddressById(addressIdInt);
            }
            return null;
        });
```

Но здесь по-моему тоже что-то не так. С Optional не совсем хорошо у меня. Здесь orElseGet выполняется в любом случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если без сторонних библиотек и самое короткое, то через регулярки:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str){
    return str.matches("[+-]?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?");
}
```

и тогда ваш метод:

```
if (isNumeric(request.params("address_id"))) {
    officeAddresses = App.officeDao.getOfficeAddressById(id);
} else {
    Integer idByMnem = App.officeDao.checkOfficeAddressExistsByMnem(mnem);
    officeAddresses = App.officeDao.getOfficeAddressById(idByMnem);
}
```

---

Очень много предложений и вариантов в вопросе на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)